# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' when the object is not type None

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a Django application that allows a view of all of a customer's financial portfolio (in this case that's various stocks, mutual funds, and "other" like a 401k)

I have a QuerySet of mutual funds filtered by customer created in my views.py file that I am trying to pass to the html template and render the list. I am running into the error in the title, though: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'.

I have verified via print statements that the QuerySet is *not* of type None, and all the data I want to use is returned correctly when I store it in a variable in my view.

I have a everything working for stocks, and it has identical functionality that works just fine, so I can't figure out the difference and why one works but the other doesn't. What would be causing this error?

Below are the code blocks that I think are directly related and the error message. Full code is at: https://github.com/apalmesano2/assignment2_part2

**The error**

```
Internal Server Error: /customer/2/portfolio/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\efs\portfolio\views.py", line 270, in portfolio
    'mutual_funds': mutual_funds,
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 993, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 676, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 802, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 864, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "C:\Users\andre\isqa8380\efsd-local\efs\portfolio\models.py", line 114, in current_mutual_fund_price
    mf_open_price = float(mf_json_data.get('Global Quote').get('05. price'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

[image: Error in browser]

**models.py**

```
class Stock(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stocks')
symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
shares = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
purchase_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)

    def created(self):
        self.recent_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer)

    def initial_stock_value(self):
        return self.shares * self.purchase_price

    def current_stock_price(self):
        symbol_f = str(self.symbol)
        main_api = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols='
        api_key = '&apikey= <MY_API_KEY>'
        url = main_api + symbol_f + api_key
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        open_price = float(json_data["Stock Quotes"][0]["2. price"])
        share_value = open_price
        return share_value

    def current_stock_value(self):
        return round((Decimal(self.current_stock_price()) * Decimal(self.shares)), 3)


class MutualFund(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mutual_funds')
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shares = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)

    def created(self):
        self.recent_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.customer)

    def initial_mutual_fund_value(self):
        return self.shares * self.purchase_price

    def current_mutual_fund_price(self):
        mf_symbol_f = str(self.symbol)
        mf_main_api = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol='
        mf_api_key = '&apikey= <MY_API_KEY>'
        mf_url = mf_main_api + mf_symbol_f + mf_api_key
        mf_json_data = requests.get(mf_url).json()
        mf_open_price = float(mf_json_data.get('Global Quote').get('05. price'))
        mf_share_value = mf_open_price
        return mf_share_value

    def current_mutual_fund_value(self):
        return round((Decimal(self.current_mutual_fund_price()) * Decimal(self.shares)), 3)
```

**views.py**

```
def portfolio(request, pk):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    customers = Customer.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now())
    investments = Investment.objects.filter(customer=pk)
    stocks = Stock.objects.filter(customer=pk)
    mutual_funds = MutualFund.objects.filter(customer=pk)
    sum_recent_value = Investment.objects.filter(customer=pk).aggregate(Sum('recent_value'))
    sum_acquired_value = Investment.objects.filter(customer=pk).aggregate(Sum('acquired_value'))
    # overall_investment_results = sum_recent_value-sum_acquired_value
    # Initialize the value of the stocks
    sum_current_stocks_value = 0
    sum_of_initial_stock_value = 0
    sum_current_mutual_fund_value = 0
    sum_initial_mutual_fund_value = 0

    # Loop through each stock and add the value to the total
    for stock in stocks:
        sum_current_stocks_value += stock.current_stock_value()
        sum_of_initial_stock_value += stock.initial_stock_value()

    for mutual_fund in mutual_funds:
        sum_current_mutual_fund_value += mutual_fund.current_mutual_fund_value()
        sum_initial_mutual_fund_value += mutual_fund.initial_mutual_fund_value()

    sum_recent_investments = sum_recent_value.get('recent_value__sum')
    sum_acquired_investments = sum_acquired_value.get('acquired_value__sum')

    portfolio_initial_total = sum_of_initial_stock_value + sum_initial_mutual_fund_value + sum_acquired_investments
    portfolio_current_total = sum_current_stocks_value + sum_current_mutual_fund_value + sum_recent_investments

    return render(request, 'portfolio/portfolio.html', {'customers': customers,
                                                        'investments': investments,
                                                        'stocks': stocks,
                                                        'sum_acquired_value': sum_acquired_value,
                                                        'sum_recent_value': sum_recent_value,
                                                        'sum_current_stocks_value': sum_current_stocks_value,
                                                        'sum_of_initial_stock_value': sum_of_initial_stock_value,
                                                        'portfolio_initial_total': portfolio_initial_total,
                                                        'portfolio_current_total': portfolio_current_total,
                                                        'sum_recent_investments': sum_recent_investments,
                                                        'sum_acquired_investments': sum_acquired_investments,
                                                        'sum_current_mutual_fund_value': sum_current_mutual_fund_value,
                                                        'sum_initial_mutual_fund_value': sum_initial_mutual_fund_value,
                                                        'mutual_funds': mutual_funds,
                                                        })
```

**portfolio.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <h2 style="padding-left: 15Px">Mutual Fund Information</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Shares</th>
            <th>Initial Mutual Fund Price</th>
            <th>Initial Mutual Fund Value</th>
            <th>Current Mutual Fund Price</th>
            <th>Current Mutual Fund Value</th>
            <th>Results</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for mutual_fund in mutual_funds %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ mutual_fund.customer }}</td>
            <td>{{ mutual_fund.symbol }}</td>
            <td>{{ mutual_fund.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ mutual_fund.shares|intcomma }}</td>
            <td>{{ mutual_fund.purchase_price|intcomma }}</td>
            <td>{{ mutual_fund.initial_mutual_fund_value|intcomma }}</td>
            <td>{{ mutual_fund.current_mutual_fund_price|intcomma }}</td>
            <<td>{{ mutual_fund.current_mutual_fund_value|intcomma }}</td>
            <td>{{ mutual_fund.current_mutual_fund_value|sub:mutual_fund.initial_mutual_fund_value|intcomma }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>Total of Initial Mutual Funds</th>
            <th>Total of Current Mutual Funds</th>
            <th>Results</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ sum_initial_mutual_fund_value|intcomma }}</td>
            <td>{{ sum_current_mutual_fund_value|intcomma }}</td>
            <td>{{ sum_current_mutual_fund_value|sub:sum_initial_mutual_fund_value|intcomma }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Fix your indentation, provide a driver program to elicit the error, and give us the *entire* error message -- include the trace-back.  Remove superfluous code and data.  *Then* we have a good starting point for finding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

It appears your variable: `mf_json_data` defined at: https://github.com/apalmesano2/assignment2_part2/blob/master/portfolio/models.py#L113 is failing to return a value, resulting in `mf_request = None`.
I recommend you ensure your `mf_json_data = requests.get(mf_url).json()`
is pulling appropriately.

Try debugging with something like this:

```py
mf_request = requests.get(mf_url)
print('MF Request:', mf_request, 'MF Request Type: ', type(mf_request))

if mf_request.status_code != 200:
    print('Bad request')
    return 'Unavailable'

mf_json_data = mf_request.json()
```

In any case, the error is occurring because your `mf_request` is `None` (causing the `NoneType` exception).

**EDIT:** Based on your comment with the return value, I would say you should be handling cases where the return of `.get('Global Quote')` is `None`.

Try something like this:

```py
    def current_mutual_fund_price(self):
        mf_symbol_f = str(self.symbol)
        mf_main_api = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol='
        mf_api_key = '&apikey=REDACTED'
        mf_url = mf_main_api + mf_symbol_f + mf_api_key
        mf_json_data = requests.get(mf_url).json()
        mf_open_price = float(mf_json_data.get('Global Quote', {}).get('05. price', 0))
        mf_share_value = mf_open_price
        return mf_share_value
```

Relevant update being:

`mf_open_price = float(mf_json_data.get('Global Quote', {}).get('05. price', 0))`

Obviously, you'll want to update the your default in `.get('05.price', 0)` with sane defaults **or** handle if the value is falsey.

Once you have updated this, you shouldn't receive the error anymore, but you will need to handle cases where no values were found.

This is fairly speculative based on your question, though.

Additionally, I recommend you redact your secrets from Github.

You'll want to rotate the secret defined at:  https://github.com/apalmesano2/assignment2_part2/blob/master/portfolio/models.py#L111 and probably define it via the environment in `settings.py`

Comment: Is there a reason why I would be able to print out the return of the variable if it's not returning anything? I get the following: `mf_json_data {'Global Quote': {'01. symbol': 'TPLGX', '02. open': '46.9200', '03. high': '46.9200', '04. low': '46.9200', '05. price': '46.9200', '06. volume': '0', '07. latest trading day': '2019-07-18', '08. previous close': '46.9500', '09. change': '-0.0300', '10. change percent': '-0.0639%'}}`

Comment: @Andrew I have updated my answer with relevant changes.  You'll want to handle cases where the price is `0` or whatever sane default you decide in your template and backend logic.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! Now I just need to figure out how to reduce my number of API calls and still get the same data since I'm using the free version haha